# How to create a MoviePipelineMasterConfig instance from file path in Python?

Tags: python, unreal-engine4

I’m trying to build a movie render queue job and assign it a pre-saved output config. The file is saved under Content\Cinematics\MoviePipeline\Presets\myConfig.uasset.

My guess would be to use the unreal.MoviePipelineExecutorJob.set_configuration(preset) method. But how do I get an instance of MoviePipelineMasterConfig from a file path to apply to the job within a Python script?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the answer I was looking for.

```
newConfig = unreal.load_asset( "/Game/Cinematics/MoviePipeline/Presets/myConfig" )
```

Will create an instance of MoviePipelineMasterConfig  from an existing file that can be used within Python scripts.